# How do you loop through a class passed to a method and retrieve it's property values in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

First, forgive me if this question is redundant to other information on the site.  I've looked through other postings regarding reflection, but can't seem to make any sense of them in terms of what I'm doing.

The idea is to pass a method a class, then loop through that objects properties and assign it's value to a return value.  The return value will later be used to create an SQL statement on the fly.  I've created the loop using PropertyInfo, and I'm able to tell the type of property based on a switch statement.  The problem is once I'm in the specific case for the property, I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to assign that particular properties value to the list to be returned later.  Here is my code, thanks in advance for any help.

```
    public List<string> BuildParametersFromObject(clsBook oBook, clsStudent oStud)
    {
        List<string> lstRetVal = new List<string>();
        string sTemp = "";
        string sPropType = "";
        int ii;
        if (oBook == null)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] ObjProperties = typeof(clsStudent).GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo StudProp in ObjProperties)
            {
                ii = 0;
                sPropType = Convert.ToString(StudProp.PropertyType);
                switch (sPropType)
                {
                    case "System.String":
                        lstRetVal.Add(StudProp.GetValue(clsStudent, null));
                        break;
                    case "System.Int32":

                        break;
                    case "System.Decimal":

                        break;
                    case "System.Boolean":

                        break;
                    case "System.DateTime":

                        break;
                }

            }
        }
        return lstRetVal;
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. If you're trying to convert everything to a string, the smells to me like code that's likely to result in gaping open sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: I convert the values as I need them to be something different (e.g. Decimal for SQL server type money, int for int, etc, etc), and I always use the parameter method for SQL statements as opposed to string concatenation...  My method is to apply the first letter of the server data type and substring to decided which type I should be adding, for instance in the insert... "i_@field1,v_@field2,b_@field3,etc

Comment: That seems like a performance drain: for example, you have a value that is originally a decimal, you convert it to string, and then must parse the string back to a decimal before sending it to the db. You won't notice that in a small amounts, but for a data layer where you don't know if it will be used to return thousands of records in a query, or run smaller queries for thousands of sessions hitting a web server, it's a performance tax you want to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not compile, since

```
StudProp.GetValue(clsStudent, null)
```

requires it's first parameter to be an object and you're giving that method what is most surely a class symbol.

Second of all, I was trying to understand what you intended to do with your two parameters:

- `clsBook oBook`
- `clsStudent oStud`

From what you wrote there I understand that if `oBook` is not null, then you go about with the adding of results to your returning list. I'll leave it at that for now.

The second biggest question mark is whether you need the `oStud` parameter whatsoever.

Say you solve the compilation problem, and your code **does** compile.
If you would try deleting the parameter altogether i.e.

```
public List<string> BuildParametersFromObject(clsBook oBook, clsStudent oStud)
```

becomes

```
public List<string> BuildParametersFromObject(clsBook oBook)
```

you would notice that your method still compiles, hence you're not using `oStud`.

You're enumerating the properties of the `clsStudent`

If you're not sure as to what I'm talking about then you can simply do the following:

- quick resolution: apply the following modifications (just below)
- longterm resolution: read more about **OOP** and **Reflection**:
  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173183(v=vs.110).aspx

**MODIFICATIONS**

```
// prepare your little filter
private static readonly Type[] allowedTypes = new Type[] { 
    typeof(bool), typeof(string), typeof(int), 
    typeof(decimal), typeof(DateTime)
};

public List<string> BuildParametersFromObject(clsBook oBook, clsStudent oStud)
{
    List<string> lstRetVal = new List<string>();
    string sTemp = "";
    string sPropType = "";
    int ii;
    if (oBook == null)
    {

        PropertyInfo[] ObjProperties = typeof(clsStudent).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo StudProp in ObjProperties)
        {
            // if the property's type is not one of the 5 magnificence
            // simply jump to the next cycle of the foreach loop
            if (!allowedTypes.Contains(StudProp.PropertyType)) 
                continue;

            object pureValue = StudProp.GetValue(oStud);
            // what you were using is not ok: StudProp.GetValue(clsStudent)
            // because you're trying to retrieve the value of a property
            // defined by the clsStudent class
            // and in the process you also need to point out an instance
            // of that particular class, but instead of doing that
            // you were pointing out an instance of Type i.e. clsStudent itself

            string stringValue = pureValue + "";
            // simply concatenate the pureValue with a blank string
            // (allowing imminent nulls to be displayed as empty strings instead of crashing your thread with NullReferenceException)

            lstRetVal.Add(stringValue);
            // just add your stringified value to the list

        }


    }
    return lstRetVal;
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

What I've done is I've modified your explicit filtering (using **switch**) to a primitive array (a list of the types you wish to support in the adding of results) and by that I've also removed the unnecessary and completely hard to maintain "by Name comparison" of types. It's much cleaner to compare types for what they are: themselves. There can be RunninThruLife's in the world, but only one of them is you.

**The biggest** error was the fact that instead of getting the properties' values from the clsStudent instance you were getting them from clsStudent itself (which is a class).

Answer (score 1):

In each of the other cases, just call ToString() on the result of GetValue().

```
StudProp.GetValue(oStud, null).ToString();
```

Obviously if you need specific formatting you would do that before adding to the list.

Comment: Thank you, I had to add the instance variable in place of the class name in order to get it to work, but this was a push in the right direction for me.  Once again, SO comes through.

Comment: Dude: clsStudent is a class symbol. This doesn't compile. Have you tried that ? It's like trying to concatenate the type **string** with the letter 'a'

Comment: typeof(clsStudent) and StudProp.GetValue(clsStudent, ... ) both mean you haven't carefully read the question and that the asker didn't understand your answer

Comment: +1 I totally agree, and I apologize for not noticing that was a class symbol instead of an object. I was trying to point out that to get those other types into a list of string, you can just call their ToString function. I would also agree that the switch is not necessary, as you point out in your answer.